# Subtract columns in R data frame but keep values of var1 or var2 when the other is NA

Tags: r, subtraction, col

I wanted to subtract one column from the other in R and this turned out more complicated than I thought.

Suppose this is my data (columns `a` and `b`) and column `c` is what I want, namely `a - b` but keeping `a` when `b==NA` and vice versa:

```
   a    b    c
1  2    1    1
2  2   NA    2
3 NA    3    3
4 NA   NA   NA
```

Now I tried different things but most of the time it returned NA when at least one column was NA. For example:

```
matrixStats::rowDiffs(data, na.rm=T) # only works for matrix-format, and returns NA's

dat$c <- dat$a - dat$b + ifelse(is.na(dat$b),dat$a,0) + ifelse(is.na(dat$a),dat$b,0) # seems like a desparately basic solution, but not even this does the trick as it also returns NA's

apply(dat[,(1:2)], MARGIN = 1,FUN = diff, na.rm=T) # returns NA's

dat$b<-dat$b*(-1)
dat$c<-rowSums(dat,na.rm=T) # this kind of works but it's a really ugly workaround
```

Also, if you can think of a `dplyr` solution, please share your knowledge. I didn't even know what to try.

Will delete this question if you think it's a duplicate of an existing one, though none of the existing threads were particularly helpful.

Comment: What are the types of the `a` and `b` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (Base R Solution):

If `df$b` is `NA` then simply take the value of `df$a` else if `df$a` is `NA` then simply take the value of `df$b` else do `df$a-df$b`

```
df$c=ifelse(is.na(df$b),df$a,ifelse(is.na(df$a),df$b,df$a-df$b))
```

Output:

```
df
   a  b  c
1  2  1  1
2  2 NA  2
3 NA  3  3
4 NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try using the [`coalesce`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.6/topics/coalesce) function from the `dplyr` package:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=c(2, 2, NA, NA), b=c(1, NA, 3, NA))
dat$c <- coalesce(dat$a - coalesce(dat$b, 0), dat$b)
dat$c

   a  b  c
1  2  1  1
2  2 NA  2
3 NA  3  3
4 NA NA NA
```

The idea here is to take `a` minus `b`, or `a` alone if `b` be `NA`.  If that entire expression is still `NA`, then it implies that `a` is also `NA`, in which case we take `b`.

Comment: Thank you, this works fine... although when I first tried it an error message popped up telling me that argument 2 Argument 2 must be type integer` (which I thought it was already). Tried again using `as.integer(dat$b) and it worked.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that the outcome of this is strange: it doesn't return a when b==NA and vice versa...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `base R` where we `replace` the `NA` elements with 0, `Reduce` it to a single `vector` by taking the rowwise difference and change the rows that have all `NA` elements to `NA`

```
df1$c <- abs(Reduce(`-`, replace(df1, is.na(df1), 0))) *
               NA^ (!rowSums(!is.na(df1)) )
df1$c
#[1]  1  2  3 NA
```

---

Or using similar method with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[!is.na(a) | !is.na(b), c := abs(Reduce(`-`, 
               replace(.SD, is.na(.SD), 0)))]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(2L, 2L, NA, NA), b = c(1L, NA, 3L, NA)), 
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "data.frame")
```